# Folder Deletion Access Denied Error from program

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to Delete the folder inside C:\Windows\temp..
But i am getting access denied error, running program as administrator.

Syntax i am using:

```
 Dim path As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows) & "\Temp\"
                System.IO.Directory.Delete(path, True)
```

Tried running syntax under Impersonation, any ideas how can I achieve this. Folders on root dir c:\ i was able to delete.
Also tried adding app.manifest file with 'requireAdministrator' .

Comment: Have you used procmon to find out if something is blocking that directorry by keeping files open ? For a temp directory this is rather likely.

Comment: o! yes, it was being used, any Idea how can i force delete the files inside temp folder...

Comment: First delete all files from that directory and then try to find out what is blocking the remaining files. Then end those processes, delete the files and then the directory. You can use PendingFileRenameOperations to delete files on reboot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try to clear the temp files first before removing the folder.  You can use the built in windows process for this as well..  after this is complete try to delete the folder.

```
    Dim p As New Process()
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "RunDll32.exe"
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 8"
    p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    p.Start()
    Dim p1 As New Process()
    p1.StartInfo.FileName = "RunDll32.exe"
    p1.StartInfo.Arguments = "InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 2"
    p1.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    p1.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    p1.Start()
    'Clear Temp Files
    'Shell "RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 8 "
    'Clear Cookies
    'Shell "RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 2"
    'Clear History
    'Shell "RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 1"
    'Clear Form data
    'Shell "RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 16"
    'Clear Svaed Passwords
    'Shell "RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 32"
```

Comment: Hmm..  is your Temp folder listed in global variables/paths for Temp?

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft has performed some modification about authorities to delete files and folders under SPECIALFOLDER specs. I believe it´s due to older security issues.

You can delete some of them ONLY IF RUNNING APP AS AN ADMINISTRATOR and others, even being an Admin, you cannot do.

Comment: Thanks, I found the Below is doing the trick:  
` My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(foundFile, FileIO.UIOption.OnlyErrorDialogs, FileIO.RecycleOption.DeletePermanently) `

But its asking confirmation from user to delete files, is there a way to pass parameter which indicates user has confirmed deletion... That should solve the issue

Comment: For sure. The confirmation acts like the Admin rights, asking for user confirmation to ensure that he has aknowledgement for this and really wants to delete the files. Good luck.